# How to set date and time 6 hour before to picked time and date?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app, here I want to use Date and time picker, To pick a date and time but I want to set result time 6 hours before picked time. How do I set this time 6 hour before the pick time with appropriate date with respect to time?
Example:
if i am pick date suppose "30sep" and time is "1:00am" then date and time I would like to display will  be "29sep"  and "7:00pm".
How do I do?
I am using following code:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == pdate) {

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            eddate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == ptime) {

            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {


                            edtime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            if(hourOfDay==00)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((17) + ":" + minute);

                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==1)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((18) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==2)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((19) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==3)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((20) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==4)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((21) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==5)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((22) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==6)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((23) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==7)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((00) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==8)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((01) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==9)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((02) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==10)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((03) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==11)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((04) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==12)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((05) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            if(hourOfDay==13)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((06) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==14)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((07) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==15)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((8) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==16)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((9) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==17)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((10) + ":" + minute );
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==18)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((11) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==19)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((12) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==20)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((13) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==21)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((14) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==22)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((15) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                            else if(hourOfDay==23)
                            {
                                tvpicktime.setText((16) + ":" + minute);
                            }
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);

            timePickerDialog.show();
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are removing 7 hours and you are not changing the day (if it's 1 AM, you should go in the previous day, but anyway you can simply call this instead of your switch statement:

```
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -6);
```

This will add -6 hours so it will remove 6 hours

**To show result in a textfield**

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
myTextField.setText(simpleDate.format(c.getTime()));
```

Comment: @rohiH this will do everything for you. he will manage hours, days, months and even years (in case of 01-01-2016). So just call this code and you are done :)

Comment: this code gives problem to 00:00am to 5:00am here it shows negative values and also not shows proper date.

Comment: @Shabbir Dhangot : what do you want to say?

Comment: @rohiH if you read [the calendar official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), add has two rules and they automatically adjust the times. so this is not going to be negative because negative value is not allowed in hours and it will automatically go to the previous day. I'm using this in my code and it's working